# Short conductive cylinder inside a coil

Tags: electromagnetism

The problem states;

> Inside a solenoid coil, a non-magnetic, conductive, solid cylinder is placed coaxially. The cylinder is shorter than the coil but has about the same diameter as the coil's turns/wraps (it fits inside). Initially, the coil has direct current running through it and the cylinder is placed between the coil's middle and one of its edges. When the current starts to reduce, the cylinder is acted upon by a **force**.
>
> What causes this force and what is its direction; towards the middle of the coil, or the nearest edge? Substantiate your answer qualitatively, taking into consideration that the coil's length can **not** be considered much greater than the diameter of its turns/wraps.

This problem was in my undergrad E/M exam and it kind of stumped me tbh. I know that there will be eddy currents on the cylinder, because of the changing magnetic field, but I can't think of a force that can push the cylinder either out of the coil or towards its middle.

Can anyone help me better understand the concepts of this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The conducting cylinder finds itself in a region of decreasing magnetic field produced by the decreasing current in he coil.
This induces an emf (Faraday) and because the cylinder is a conductor, induced (eddy) currents flow within the cylinder.

Lenz tells us that the the direction of the induced currents will be such as to try and reduce the effect of the decreasing magnetic field.

The interaction between the induced current and the changing field will produce a force on the cylinder which will try and move the cylinder towards the region where there is a larger magnetic field ie towards the centre of the coil.

The statement

> . . . taking into consideration that the coil's length can **not** be considered much greater than the diameter of its turns/wraps.

Is there to tell you that the magnetic field inside the coil is not uniform (and a maximum in the middle).

Answer (score -1):

It's a result of Lenz's Law. A change in the coil-field causes the induced field to change and the cylinder moves.